# How to describe GXT Window from UiBinder?

Tags: java, xml, gwt, gxt, uibinder

I have a simple gxt window:

```
public class MainWindow extends Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        Label test = new Label("Test");
        add(test);
    }
}
```

And I want to describe the same window from UiBinder. This code work perfectly:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:gxt="urn:import:com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget">
    <gxt:Window>
    </gxt:Window>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

But when I add `<gxt:Label>Test</gxt:Label>` in gxt:Window element I have error:

```
[ERROR] Found unexpected child element Element <gxt:Label>
```

What I do wrong? What expected in Window element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext GWT 2.x doesn't support UiBinder (the reason being the absence of public API to create custom element parsers in GWT: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4461).

You can add a component `gxt:Windows` but that's it, you can't add child elements under `gxt:Window`, since there's no element parser for any of the gxt:Window superclasses. GWT's Panels extend GWT's `HasWidgets` and there's an element parser for them: [HasWidgetsParser](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/uibinder/elementparsers/HasWidgetsParser.java), which calls `add()` for each child element.

It's possible to workaround this and I guess that's what they've done for [Ext GWT 3 beta](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-gwt-3-0-beta-1-available/) since it claims "full UiBinder support", so you can try that.